# How to save excel file faster with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, save

I have an excel file worth 150 mb and with only one worksheet( master worksheet).As you can imagine it has lots of calculations in it. What I am doing currently is, running a VBA in it to make a new file and copy that worksheet into the new file ( lets say working file) and then deleting some rows from it. For that I am using VBA. the problem is, when I save this file, it takes a lot of time because in the back end , master file (with lots of calculations) is still open. Is there any way , I can save the working file , without getting affected by the big file in the back end.
.....Any suggestions would be appreciated......
thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you need the calculations or just the data?  If you just need data, can you save a copy as a csv file. That's just a text file to manipulate then?

Comment: I need calculations also.....

Comment: Assuming you have already calculated your results on the master, have you tried turning calculations off before you save then back on before you finish?

Comment: Yes Dave, I have included turning calculations "manual" before saving it. I have calculated results in master. When I copy it , I delete some rows, then results get recalculated again, but I turn off calculations at that moment for saving time. It still takes a lot of time.

Comment: a) `.UsedRange.Cells = .UsedRange.Cells.Value` b) save as XLSB.

Comment: I did not get your point pnuts...

Comment: jeeped--Thanks for your suggestions. for a)...I will loose formulas  b) I can try this...

Comment: c) get rid of all conditional formatting d) minimize use of merged cells and custom number formatting

Comment: C) already no formatting in there   d)  no merged cells

Comment: An alternative way could be to query your mastersheets data for what you need and rebuild your formula. Difficult to tell really as I don't know if your master sheet is self contained or if it is dependant on other data sources. (Vlookups etc).  If its self contained i.e. all your data is in your master sheet and your formula reference the same sheet you could rebuild all your formula 'in query'. I do quite a bit of this when handling bw data.

Comment: you can save as .xlsb. this will speed up the file and all calculations will stay intact.

Comment: The master being open in the background doesn't affect the saving of the copy. It seems that you do copy a lot of data and formulas in the new file so the most significant improvement you can make is with the suggested .xlsb - file size will be less than a third, and it will save a LOT faster

Comment: How complex are the calculations?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that calculations are making it slower. Try to use:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = false
```

at te beginning of the code and

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

at the end. Or simply make the worksheet invisible (visible=false) while calculating and saving. Try to microoptimize string operations. If you are able to, please, post some code to let us make an opinion about it.